# How to format numbers from 0 to 000 in php?

Tags: php

I need to change the format of the integer. I know that needs to apply `sprintf` function but not sure how to apply properly.

The format turn 0 to 000.

**E.g turn 1 to 001 & 19 to 019.**

i get item code from URL.

```
$catCode=isset($_GET["cat"]) ? $_GET["cat"] : "ac";
$itemCode=isset($_GET["itemCode"]) ? $_GET["itemCode"] : "001";

foreach ($productArr[$catCode] as $imgNumber => $productDetail) {
            array_push($arr, $imgNumber);
            $imgNumber = $arr;
        }

//count the total number of items in the array
        $totalItem = count($arr);
        $prevItem = ($itemCode + $totalItem - 2) % $totalItem + 1;
        $nextItem = $itemCode % $totalItem + 1;

        if ($itemCode > $totalItem || $itemCode < 1) {
            $itemCode = 1;
        }

echo"<a href='http://localhost/collectionDetail.php?cat={$catCode}&itemCode={$prevItem}' ><img src='images/arrow_left.jpg'> </a>";
echo"<a href='http://localhost/collectionDetail.php?cat={$catCode}&itemCode={$nextItem}' ><img src='images/arrow_right.jpg'> </a>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, concatenate `sprintf` with `.` :

```
echo "<a href='http://localhost/collectionDetail.php?cat=".sprintf("%03d",$catCode)."&itemCode=".sprintf("%03d",$prevItem)."' ><img src='images/arrow_left.jpg'> </a>";
echo "<a href='http://localhost/collectionDetail.php?cat=".sprintf("%03d",$catCode)."&itemCode=".sprintf("%03d",$nextItem)."' ><img src='images/arrow_right.jpg'> </a>";
```

Comment: Thanks, Your's work. I try `$format = 000;
            $itemCode = sprintf("%3d",$itemCode);` but i failed.

Comment: When `$itemCode = 0` it should also print `000`. What it failed?